# Mean-value theorems (other than Cauchy's, Lagrange's or Rolle's)

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request

I am looking for '*Mean Value Theorems*' that are different from the ones usually proposed during calculus courses (i.e. Cauchy's, Lagrange's or Rolle's).

> ***Question:*** Do you know any other *mean value theorems* or also generalizations of
>   the three mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing some time ago, and I found the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and the references cited there very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Mean Value Theorem for integrals says that if $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous then there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = f(c) (b-a)$$

The latter is a corollary of the following.

Let $f,p : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$, with $f$ continuous, $p$ integrable, with $p(x) \geq 0 , \forall x \in [a,b]$. There exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^b f(x)p(x) dx = f(c)\int_a^b p(x) dx$$